# Python pandas dataframe: Count number of elements a in column greater or smaller than a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This code will count the number of elements in column `c2` that have value greater than or equal 3

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['A', 'B','C','D','E'], 'c2': [3, 1, 0,2,5]})
count=df.loc[:,'c2']
count=count[~ (count<3)] 
count=count.shape[0]
```

Is there a direct way of counting these elements instead of a three line code?

Answer (score 2):

You can update your code to add the condition and do the count in one single line as below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['A', 'B','C','D','E'], 'c2': [3, 1, 0,2,5]})
count=df[df['c2'] >= 3].count().shape[0]
print(count) # prints 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Invert logic for greater or equal by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) like `3` and for count `True`s values use `sum`:

```
count = df['c2'].ge(3).sum()
```

what working same like compare for less by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) with inverted mask:

```
count = (~df['c2'].lt(3)).sum()
```